# Nix build error: experimental Nix feature 'nix-command' is disabled

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

I have this error when I try to build plutus

```
:~/code/plutus$ nix build -f default.nix plutus.haskell.packages.plutus-core
error: experimental Nix feature 'nix-command' is disabled; use '--extra-experimental-features nix-command' to override
```

I also tried this, but I am still getting errors

```
:~/code/plutus$ nix --extra-experimental-features nix-command build -f default.nix plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-core.components.library
error: executing SQLite statement 'pragma synchronous = normal': unable to open database file (in '/nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite')
```

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this is a single user installation. Are you running the nix command as the same user that installed nix? That would explain the unable to open database file error. You could validate this looking at the permissions/ownership of the sqlite file in question.

To allow nix-command and flakes, you can create `/etc/nix/nix.conf` with the contents:

```
experimental-features = nix-command flakes
```

I'd also recommend adding the binary caches in that file as well.

Comment: Thanks this error got cleared.Thanks